# Send whole email using Triggered Send with HTML__Body

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I'm trying to send email using Triggered Send and this Guide:

[Send TriggeredSend Email](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/send_triggeredsend_email.htm)

I was able to create `HTML__Body` profile attribute and send simple email.
However when my email exceeds 4000 I have subscriber error:

> "The subscriber is missing required attribute value for HTML__Body"

Based on knowledge base this should work:
[Knowledge Base](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220898&language=en_US&type=1)

Based on other message on this forum I tried to create Data Extension and remove `HTML__Body` from **'Profile Management'** but then my triggered definition complains during save that email cannot pass validation. The same happens when I'm validating email and there is no `HTML__Body` attribute.

How to link (enter) `HTML__Body` from **'Data Extensions'** into email?
I believe that usage will be the same as it is now? once I fill finally link this.

Comment: In this [Knowledge Base](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220898&language=en_US&type=1) they have mentioned you just need to remove field length not the field `HTML__Body`

Comment: @VikasTiwari You cannot remove field length in profile management. It is mandatory (if not set it is setting value to 50 chars). I can remove field length in Data Extensions and I removed, however I have no idea how I can use data extension field inside Email definition.